# Xcode iOS add section and row in this section only

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to add Sections and add rows in the last section created.

But When I add a section and after add a row it add rows for all section and I want only to the last created section.

I do this :

```
@interface SectionTestViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionsArray;
    NSMutableArray *rowsInSectionsArray;
    NSInteger currentSection;
}
@end

@implementation SectionTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

    sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowsInSectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    currentSection = 0;
}

#pragma tableview delegate and datasource methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionsArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rowsInSectionsArray.count;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

A action of a button to add Sections :

```
- (IBAction)addSectionButton:(id)sender {
    [sectionsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %lu", (unsigned long)sectionsArray.count]];

    currentSection++;

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

A action of a button to add Row :

```
- (IBAction)addRowButton:(id)sender {
    [rowsInSectionsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ligne %lu", (unsigned long)rowsInSectionsArray.count]];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Your returning the same array, `rowsInSectionsArray`, for every section in the table. So of course when you add an object to it, it will return it for every section. `rowsInSectionsArray` should be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather do something like this:

```
@interface SectionTestViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionsArrays;
    NSMutableArray *rowsInSectionsArray;
    NSInteger currentSection;
}
@end

@implementation SectionTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

    sectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    rowsInSectionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    currentSection = 0;
}

#pragma tableview delegate and datasource methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionsArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [rowsInSectionsArrays objectAtIndex:section].count;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

An action of a button to add Sections :

```
- (IBAction)addSectionButton:(id)sender {
    [sectionsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %lu", (unsigned long)sectionsArray.count]];
    [rowsInSectionsArrays addObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

    currentSection++;

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

An action of a button to add Row at last section :

```
- (IBAction)addRowButton:(id)sender {
    [[rowsInSectionsArray objectAtIndex:currentSection] addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ligne %lu", (unsigned long)[rowsInSectionsArray objectAtIndex:currentSection].count]];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

I just converted rowsInSectionsArray to an array of arrays. Each array it contains, contains the rows for one section.

Be sure to do the same at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.